# Visual C++ GUI Functions stop responding when active window changes

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++-2010

I'm writing a program in Visual C++ 2010 Express that accepts keypresses from the user and changes the GUI text to reflect that they pressed something. I create three threads, one to run the form, one to check for input and edit the GUI, and one to check for input and respond to the input (by generating keys back). However, after the program starts, if I switch to a different window than the GUI, the GUI threads will stop working. The rest of the program will continue just fine, but I can't inject (using delegates) into the GUI thread to change the text on the GUI.

I'll post code snippets of what I think is the source of the problem, but I can post more complete code if needed (but it's not written to be read by other people).

```
DWORD WINAPI form_run(void* ignore){ //thread to run the GUI
    Form1^ form = gcnew Form1(); //create a GUI form object
    ThreadStart^ threadDelegate = gcnew ThreadStart( form, &MacroPack::Form1::change_macro_state ); //thread to check for input and change GUI text
    Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread( threadDelegate ); //make the thread
    newThread->Start(); //start the thread
    Application::Run(form); //run the GUI
    done = true; //once the GUI finishes, this bool will alert the other threads to close
    return 0;
}
```

That is the first thread to be created in the main() thread, called by:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&form_run, NULL, 0, &form_thread); //form thread is a DWORD to identify the thread
```

That thread creates a thread that runs this function (cut down, but everything cut out is a renamed copy of everything else):

```
public: System::Void change_macro_state(){ //part of a class called Form1, which is the GUI
        normal_delegate^ normal_del; //delegate to access an already-running thread in the GUI
        normal_del = gcnew normal_delegate(this, &MacroPack::Form1::normal_state); //create the delegate
        while(!done){ //keep this thread alive to check for input
            if((GetKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x80) != 0){ //if the down arrow is pressed
                Sleep(200); //waits for another thread to set a bool for the thread to be invoked
                this->label12->Invoke(normal_del); //call a function that injects into the GUI thread that changes the GUI text
            }
            Sleep(1); //to slow down on CPU consumption
        }
    }
```

That thread injects into the GUI thread (NOTE: I recently learned Visual C++, so I barely understand delegates and how to avoid cross-thread calls, so I don't know if "inject" is the right word for what delegates do) that calls this function to edit the text:

```
private: System::Void normal_state(){ //changes the GUI label text
             if(normal_active){ //this bool is changed in another thread, which is why I have the Sleep(200); before this is called
                label12->Text="Normal - Inactive"; //change the text
             }
             else if(!normal_active){ //this bool is changed in another thread, which is why I have the Sleep(200); before this is called
                label12->Text="Normal - Active"; //change the text
             }
         }
```

I won't include the third thread created because all it does is check if the same key (down arrow) is pressed, and change the normal_active bool. I placed the bool change in that thread because even when the GUI stops working, that thread will continue fine.

RECAP: The GUI won't let me change the text of a label through delegates when I switch away from the GUI window (even if I switch back it doesn't work).

EDIT: I came back to it overnight, and it works fine. I didn't change any code, and it works exactly like it should. I'm not sure what the issue is...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you manipulate the UI elements from within other(work) threads, I suggest you could rewrite your code , only manipulate UI elements in UI threads(here, it's your main thread), and if when you want to change the UI elements when you in other threads , send message to the main thead. take a try, good luck!

Comment: I thought that's what delegates did?